# How do I use data from a UITextField as an Array in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitextfield

How do I use data from a UITextField as an Array in Swift? Example:  I created the UITextField in ViewController and in it the user inserts: "1, 3, 8, 9, 10, 20" (without the ""). How can I convert this information into an Array in the programming of swift 4 and/or 5 ???

To have as a result:

```
var arrayInt: [Int] = [mytextField]
arrayInt = [1, 3, 8, 9, 10, 20]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` method if Character `isWholeNumber` property is false and map the resulting elements to Int:

```
let numbers = textField.text!.split{!$0.isWholeNumber}.compactMap({Int($0)})
numbers  // [1, 3, 8, 9, 10, 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the text on the UITextField and use .split() method with separator.

```
"1, 3, 8, 9, 10, 20".split(separator: ",")
```

That will give you a String array with all the numbers and you'd just have to convert them to Ints.

Edited to exactly match the requirements:

```
.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "").split(separator: ",").compactMap({Int($0)})
```

Comment: Or `"1, 3, 8, 9, 10, 20".split(separator: ", ").compactMap({Int($0)})`. Note the separator being "comma space".